# Django Found another file with destination path

Tags: python, django

I am trying to deploy the app on GCP but when I run the following command:

> python manage.py collectstatic

It returns:

> Found another file with the destination path
>   'admin\css\autocomplete.css'. It will be ignored since only the first
>   encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure
>   every static file has a unique path.
>
> Found another file with the destination path 'admin\css\base.css'. It
>   will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If
>   this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique
>   path.

And many other like this.

Here's my Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/yantra-packs/static/'
# STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]


PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'), ]
```

Where is it that I am providing two paths for the static files?

Answer (score 0):

The [findstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#findstatic) command will help to debug.

---

The default value of `STATICFILES_FINDERS` is:

```
[
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',     # finds files stored in the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting.
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder', # finds files stored in the 'static' subdirectory of each app.
]
```

Hence, even though you only have:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'), ]
```

`AppDirectoriesFinder` will find files stored in the `static` subdirectory of `each app`.

---

Also, you might want to look at the Django's official documentation describing the [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) command.